# How to check if ostrstream is full?

Tags: c++, stream

First off, I know ostrstream is depricated, but refactoring to ostringstream isn't really an option in this case.

Currently, I am simply checking if the stream has the bad bit set after an `<<` operation:

Example (yes, very simplified):

```
char* buf = new char[10];
std::ostrstream tempOut(buf, 10);

tempOut << "To many charactors to fit in the buffer";

if (tempOut.bad()) {
   // Do what needs to be done to allocate a bigger buf
}
```

Is there a better way to check an make sure the bad state is because of an overflow and not some other issue?

Comment: Idiomatically, I'd say `if (!(tempOut << "Two many characters to fit in the buffer")) { /* handle error */ }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a better way to check an make sure the bad state is because of an overflow and not some other issue?

Call [exceptions()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions) method to set which exceptions will be thrown. That is a proper c++ way of handling errors. You'll have to handle exceptions at places where you know how to resolve errors.

So, I would do it like this :

```
char* buf = new char[10];
std::ostrstream tempOut(buf, 10);
tempOut.exceptions(std::ios::badbit);

try
{
tempOut << "To many charactors to fit in the buffer";
}
catch( const std::exception & e )
{
  //resolve error
}
```

---

> Is there a better way to check an make sure the bad state is because of an overflow and not some other issue?

No, not really. You have to know which operation can cause which errors, and handle it. Good things about exceptions are

- you can not ignore them.
- you do not have to handle the error at the place where it occurred.